# Can you explain the difference between AIDL and Service?

Tags: android, aidl

Please mention the difference between an AIDL and an android Service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below link may be helpful to you.

http://www.anddev.org/remote_service_tutorial-t8127.html

Comment: Avoid giving links. Provide decent explanation. Thank you